# I can't load multiple times a file with inside of it an empty list

Tags: python

I need to load more than one time a file with inside of it and empty list.
At first I tried:

```
import pickle
file_example = open("file.cpk","wb")
empty_list = []
pickle.dump(empty_list,file_example)
file_example.close()

def file_open():
    file_open.file = open("file.pck","rb")
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
    file_open() 
file_open()
```

but it said "Ran out of input". I found that I have to use .seek to load more than one time the same file, so I did this:

```
import pickle
file_example = open("file.cpk","wb")
empty_list = []
pickle.dump(empty_list,file_example)
file_example.close()

def file_open():
    file_open.file = open("file.pck","rb")
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
    file_open.empty_list.seek(0)
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
file_open()
```

And now says "'list' object has no attribute 'seek'". How can I load more than one time that file?

Comment: You are calling `seek` method on list. Call it on file object instead (in your case `file_open.file.seek(0)`)

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call seek on the file object:

```
import pickle
file_example = open("file.pck","wb")
empty_list = []
pickle.dump(empty_list,file_example)
file_example.close()

def file_open():
    file_open.file = open("file.pck","rb")
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
    file_open.file.seek(0)
    file_open.empty_list = pickle.load(file_open.file)
file_open()
```

Comment: Thats the problem! Thank you!